# Java println: Windows vs Linux

Tags: java, windows, linux, newline, println

I have a java program that writes a file to a remote machine file system using the jcifs library -samba stuff; SmbFile=>SmbFileOutputStream=>PrintStream and the I use the common println(String). Everything worked fine till I moved my application to a linux machine and now the printed file on my remote windows machine looks weird.

I believe the problem is how the two OSs handle the CR, LF that are inserted by the println() function. My 'jar' is executed once a day and it's triggered by the 'crontab' through a 'sh' launch file.

- Is there a way to fix the issue without touching the java code?
- Is there a way to write a java program to make it work on both kind of OSs (possibly all of them)?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try playing around with the system property **"line.separator"**. You can read [this for reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708991/setting-java-vm-line-separator)

Comment: Thanks! 'java -jar -Dline.separator=$'\r\n' FileName.jar' did the job for a windows machine without modifying the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

If your java file runs in a linux machine println will use the linux standard "\n"
If you want it to allways use \r\n, without changing system properties, simply replace your
println("text") with print("text\r\n"). Or create a custom function printWindowsLine to do that

Comment: Rather than a custom function, see the line.separator system property mentioned by @Suraj

Comment: I rather use a custom method. I don't want to mess with system wide properties that can affect everything that runs in the same jvm. But it is up to you.

Comment: \r\n or custom functions will both link my jar to a specific OS, I was hoping in something more flexible. The line.separator would get the property of the system where the jar is launched, right? And this wouldn't work either if I save the file in a remote machine I guess.. Suraj's solution works well and require only a little extra configuration

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the new line separator in the file. In linux, there is a utility called [dos2unix](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) that converts the new line separator of an existing file from dos/windows to linux/unix.

Comment: thanks, but I would have to go the way around -unix2dos- and plus this would be hard to integrate in the way my solution works.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println is a PrintStream, which [uses the environment setting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28%29) for [line.separator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) as its, well, line separator.  One solution to your problem would be to pass in -Dline.separator argument.

Probably the best solution though is to just use view your file with a better editor.  Notepad++ and many others on Windows will understand both types of line endings, while notepad will not.  Even the builtin wordpad does a better job of displaying unix file endings.

Comment: I love Notepad++! But unfortunately (or fortunately) the file doesn't have to be read by a human