# Can't create PHP project from SVN Repository with Netbeans 7.0.1

Tags: php, svn, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

I'm trying to create a PHP project from SVN Repository with Netbeans 7.0.1 but I can't.
Context: There are three users, two uses Macs and I'm using Windows 7 64 bits. I needed to add

```
-J-Dline.separator=LF
```

to netbeans.conf to be able to work with the Mac's developers.

Everything was working until a SVN folder restructure went on. Now I can checkout the project but then, I select to create a new PHP project from Existiing sources and it says

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Checking in the file nbproject/project.xml, this is the content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>LF<project xmlns="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/project/1">LF    <type>org.netbeans.modules.php.project</type>LF    <configuration/>LF</project>LF
```

Which seems to be wrong.
I really don't know what else I can try.
Any help will be really appretiated.
Thanks! Guillermo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I'm able to work again.
The solution was to uninstall Netbeans (including the config folder under Users/[User].netbeans
The problem before was that the uninstall process didn't work (nothing happened) so I read that I can manually remove the Netbeans installation folder and install it again, but that procedure didn't remove .netbeans folder under Users folder and I was back in the starting point. After the deletion of every folder related to Netbeans and installing it again, it finally worked as expected.
Regards. Guillermo.

Answer (score 1):

As a short-term fix, edit the nbproject/project.xml and replace those LFs with newlines, and re-try the 'create a new PHP project from Existing sources'

Longer term, you may need to file a bug with http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html, line termination is covered at http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqEditorEOLs, which suggests this is unnecessary.

Based on [Setting Java VM line.separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708991/setting-java-vm-line-separator), you should be using `-Dline.separator=$'\n'`, but you might have better results editing the subversion client config, and adding the following:

```
[miscellany]
enable-auto-props=yes

[auto-props]
# Repeat for all text files in your project
*.html = svn:eol-style=native
*.xml = svn:eol-style=native
*.php = svn:eol-style=native
*.js = svn:eol-style=native
```

Comment: I tried that, but the problem is when I go and create a new project it says: Sources directory is already NetBeans project (maybe only in memory).
So I need to deleted the nbproject folder, and everything goes to the starting point.

Comment: Did you change the -Dline.separator option? That's the source of the problem with a corrupt project.xml

Answer (score 1):

I used Netbeans with SVN plugin in a team project for a few month. We often encountered problems with non-successful commits, tree conflicts and random losses of code updates.

Maybe it was my messy working style, I don't blame Netbeans for that. But then I switched to Tortoise for taking care of the subversion repo and Netbeans for coding work. Especially checkouts and editing conflicts are a lot more comfortable with Tortoise. After the seperation, things run a lot smoother. My 0,02$.