# setting JVM "line.separator" property for mvn test command

Tags: java, linux, windows, maven, special-characters

We have a number of unit tests which assemble a multi-line string in memory and compare it against a reference string in a file.

We've gotten a bit carried away and implemented the tests to use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to make the code OS-agnostic, but the reference files are just files with `\n` line endings (Linux), so the tests which compared generated content to reference file content fail on a Windows machine because `System.getProperty("line.separator")` returns `\r\n` there.

This is test code so we'll probably simply define a final String `LINE_ENDING="\n"` and update tests to use it instead of the `"line.separator"` property value, but that said, I'd really like to understand why I'm unable to specify a different line separator. I tried `mvn -DargLine="-Dline.separator=\n" test`, but the newline special character appears to have been interpreted as a literal letter `"n"` so tests failed again. To my surprise, trying `\\n` instead of `\n` made no difference, either.

Can anyone show how one would set the `line.separator` parameter properly?

Final note: the above commands were issued on a Linux machine. When running one of the tests from within Eclipse on a Windows, the `\n` special character (passed in the debug configuration as a JVM parameter `-Dline.separator=\n`) seems to be interpreted as the literal value `"\\n"`. Searching the web proves frustratingly fruitless.

Comment: Why not fix the tests which are broken, since they are not testing the right thing?

Comment: See this one: [how to do it safely](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23643741/620908) - tl;dr - don't do it globally it may affect libs that you are using; wrap the section (in the code) that needs to use a different line.separator with a [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) supported by an [AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html)

Comment: Let me repeat: I'm aware that the tests not testing the right thing (I've tried to clarify that in my question, apparently badly). As for the safety issue, these are unit tests: they don't depend on external libraries other than those surefire needs to run the tests, so I don't see a problem there and would still like to learn how one would go about setting the line.separator JVM system property from the CLI, even though we'll most probably simply use "\n" explicitly in tests as the reference output was produced using the same line separator. I'm asking to learn, not necessarily to apply here.

Comment: I have a similar problem and just `replaceAll("\r","")` on the strings to compare. Having said that I'd like to know how to emulate Windows style endings to know that my tests will pass on Windows as well as linux.