# CRLF Text format issue after Migrate app from Windows to Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, tomcat, migration

I'm having issues after migrate one of my corporate apps from Windows-Apache Tomcat to Linux (we have to save some money in licensing).
After migrate (Tomcat migration - WAR File) to a server with the same original config (Tomcat and Java versions), one of the functions of the app (generate plain text files) lose their format when we open the files on Windows Notepad. If we open the files on Notepad++, the files looks good and the only way to re-open fine on Windows Notepad is using the EOL conversion (to windows CR LF).
The main issue that we have is that the mentioned app is a very old one and we don't own the code (only have the folder site).
It's possible to apply some config to Java or Apache to change the plain text format?

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The answer to question "[Setting Java VM line.separator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3708991/5221149)" shows how to specify the line separator, but make sure to read the other answers too about the problems with doing so.

Comment: @Andreas - Why didn't you move to close? Is there something wrong with your duplicate?

Comment: @jww I wasn't sure if it would satisfy OP, since this question is about a Tomcat web server. The ramifications when applied to a web server may prevent that answer from being applicable.

Comment: As i understand, the solutions provided applies for a code change (and we don't have access to the app code). We're looking for a possibly solution changing the global config of Java or Tomcat. Thanks.