# How can I force Java stdout on windows to use the "\n" line seperator?

Tags: java, windows, git

I am writing a front-end for `git fast-import`. I have to use java (more specifically Java 7) as the system I am extracting from really only has a java api. I have everything working the way I think it should except when I pipe my stdout over to `fast-import` I am getting this error:

```
fatal: Branch name doesn't conform to GIT standards: refs/heads/master
```

When I look at the line endings I see that there is a `cr` `lf` versus the `lf` that should be there. I tried using a `StringBuilder` to build an output string inserting `\n`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new Stringbuilder("commit ref/heads/master\n");
```

that didnt work....

So thinking it was something with `StringBuilder` I tried just writing to `stdout` using `print()` leaving the sepcified line endings as `\n`.

```
System.out.print("commit refs/heads/master\n");
```

That did not seem to do the trick....

as a last ditch effort I tried:

```
System.setProperty("line.seperator","\n");
System.out.println("commit refs/heads/master");
```

that also failed failed...

So is there a way to write a simple `lf` in place of the standard `cr` `lf` in in a windows console?

UPDATE:

`System.out.print("some text\n")` still yields a `cr` `lf`.

for more reference here is the code snippet:

```
if(!isdevPath)
    System.out.print("commit refs/heads/master\n");
else
    System.out.print("commit refs/heads/devpath/" + devPathName + "\n");        
System.out.print("mark " + rev.getRevision() + "\n");
System.out.print("committer " + rev.getAuthor() + " <> " + convertDate(rev.date) + "\n");
System.out.print(exportData(rev.getDescription()) + " \n" );
```

I ran this in powershell like this: `Java -jar >> text.txt` and I am still getting the same error when I pipe to `git fast-import`

and here is a snap shot from notepad++ where you can see line endings

[image]

**Solution**
The answer to this is simply you can't do it in a windows based shell. If I run this through bash in a windows system it retains the line feeds from a `print()` statement. So the answer is use `print()` statements with a `\n` where you want your line feeds. Then run the jar and pipe to git fast-import from bash.

Comment: 'That did not seem to do the trick': it certainly should have. Try it again.

Comment: You have typo in line.separator. You have seperator :)

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I have done some more testing and `print("\n")` and changing the `line.separator` property (thank you @gtiwari333) seemed to work for a `PrintWriter` but I am still getting the same results for the System.out `Stream`

Comment: There is nothing in `PrintStream` that would do that, or in the `BufferedWriter` that it uses either.

Comment: You may be able to use `java -Dline.separator=` to achieve what you need with System.out.println, but I cannot see how to provide escape code for `\n` when using -D parameter on Windows. My answer below works but uses PrintWriter. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708991/setting-java-vm-line-separator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Although my previous answer works, there is an easier way to run Java on Windows with a different `line.separator`. Unfortunately it isn't easy to set up `java -Dline.separator=xxx` as a direct command line parameter as Windows mangles the property value, but you can use `java @argfile` instead.

All you need is do is use Windows `CMD.EXE` to create a config file for the OS style line separator property:

```
echo -Dline.separator="\n"   > gnu.args
echo -Dline.separator="\r\n" > windows.args
```

This `LineSeparator` test program shows the effect:

```
public static void main(String ... args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("line.separator="+Arrays.toString(System.lineSeparator().getBytes()));

    // Test writing a file:
    Path out = Path.of("/tmp/out.tmp");
    List<String> list = List.of("");
    Files.write(out, list);

    // Dump the bytes used:
    System.out.println("Line "+list+" saved as bytes "+Arrays.toString(Files.readAllBytes(out)));
}
```

Run on Windows or Linux to see the effect:

```
// WINDOWS simulate GNU/Linux
java @gnu.args LineSeparator.java
=> prints
line.separator=[10]
Line [] saved as bytes [10]

// Linux simulate Windows
java @windows.args LineSeparator.java
=> prints
line.separator=[13, 10]
Line [] saved as bytes [13, 10]
```

See also [Setting Java VM line.separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708991/setting-java-vm-line-separator)

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

`PrintStream` uses `System.lineSeparator()`. Any code you add which sets a new value for `line.separator` (note correct spelling) `System.setProperty("line.separator","\n");` will not change  `System.lineSeparator()`.

You can make a new PrintStream but there are many places to override to make it work for all println() calls. Instead it is easier to switch your code to use `PrintWriter` which requires one override `println` method to ensure you always get right endings you wish:

```
static PrintWriter newPrintWriter(Writer out, String lineSep)
{
    return new PrintWriter(out) {
        public void println() {
            print(lineSep);
        }
    };
}
```

This code will write out correctly:

```
    PrintWriter out = newPrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out), "\n");
    out.println("commit refs/heads/master");
    out.println("mark XYZ");
    out.println("committer ABC");
    out.flush();
```

You can test with this to show the line ending changes:

```
    try(PrintWriter out = newPrintWriter(new FileWriter("unix.txt"), "\n"))
    {
        out.println("commit refs/heads/master");
        out.println("mark XYZ");
        out.println("committer ABC");
    }
    try(PrintWriter out = newPrintWriter(new FileWriter("pc.txt"), "\r\n"))
    {
        out.println("commit refs/heads/master");
        out.println("mark XYZ");
        out.println("committer ABC");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't print lines:

```
System.out.print("some text\n"); // note print, not println
```

Comment: That seems very unlikely. Maybe your copy-paste is putting the windows endings in, or powershell.

Comment: @Cureck In fact it is impossible. Clearly you aren't running the code you think you're running.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne and @bohemian I think the power shell is converting the `lf` to  `cr`  `lf``